# Elasticsearch head plugin replacement in 2022

Tags: elasticsearch

Haven't touched ES for a while and this morning trying to setup a cluster to play with, and then realised the good old `head` plugin is not maintained anymore, did a bit of google, found `ElasticHQ`, also realised it's not maintained anymore.

So what opensource tool can I use to manage the ES cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome back!! I'm heavily using the following two very good head-like tools:

- https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro
- https://elasticvue.com/

Comment: cerebro doesn't seem to be maintained anymore :(